# How to fetch all module names with their controllers and action in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to Yii framework and I want to know how can I get the module name along with its controller and actions

```
$modules = \Yii::$app->getModules();
```

But I did't get satisfactory result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
// get the module to which the currently requested controller belongs
$module = \Yii::$app->controller->module;
```

check [yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html) for modules and [reference for controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html)

Comment: this only gives the name of current module but i want to know that how can i fetch all the modules name present in the project with their controllers and actions..

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not useful for you but in the doc I have not found what you are looking for. I don't know what can serve a function of this type

Answer (score 0):

You can get action + controllers listing using extension named ACL.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/acl/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Yii::$app->modules;
```

It will give you all the modules available in`config.php`